# Close my MainWindow And reopen It Wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to Close and reopen my MainWindow.

I have my MainWindow and I put some Page in with Navigation.

Now I try to place a button Disconnect and I want that it close the MainWindow and reopen it because I want that the program close all BackgroundWorker and all things the application is running.

I tried something like:

```
private void Disconnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var test = sender as Window;
    MainWindow test2 = new MainWindow();
    test2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    test.Close();
}
```

But don't work.

Or probably can I make something that close all with Navigation between Page ?

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution:

```
try
{
   // Run the program again
   Process.Start(Application.ResourceAssembly.Location);

   // Close the Old one
   Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
}
catch
{ }
```